Setting group.instance.id for Kafka Connect
I am trying to set the group.instance.id parameter for Kafka Connect connectors so I can utilize Static Membership for the workers.
I believe this parameter has to be unique at the consumer level.
For the case of group.id, we can just set it in the worker.properties file:
group.id=connect-$connectorname

However, where can we set the group.instance.id ? If it is set in the worker.properties file, can it be unique at the consumer level?
Or do we need to manually set it in the function where the consumers and their IDs are generated?
I was thinking it would be good to have it be set to the consumer id (something like instance-id123, instance-id321, ... but not sure where to add the logic to do that.

Unclear if you're trying to set this for workers or sink connectors, but for the worker consumer processes, you'd set consumer.group.instance.id in the connect-distributed.properties, for example.

It would be for sink connectors, so for example the connector which writes to S3. Do you know where I would set group.instance.id for that? If not do you have an example of how it's set in connect-distributed.properties?

You can try consumer.override.group.instance.id in the sink connector properties rather than the worker (consumer prefix is for the worker, consumer.override is for specific connectors)

What should the value be set as?

It can be any unique identifier, I believe

Have an example of how you set yours up?

I've not used kafka connect in a while. Don't remember if we applied this property. As mentioned, the value could be anything.
